# How can I show that the system of non-linear differential equations does not have periodic orbits?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

The system is the following: $\left\{\begin{matrix}
x'=&2x-x^5-xy^4 \\ 
y'=&y-y^3-x^2y 
\end{matrix}\right.$.

What I did was to find singular points in the system: from which I got the following singular points: $(0,0); (0,1);(0, -1);(\sqrt[4]{2},0);(\sqrt[4]{2},0)$. Then, I have classified them if they are attractors, chair, etc. But I do not know how to prove that the system does not have periodic orbits. Can someone guide me? Please. Thanks in advance. Best regards.

Comment: Have you learned any of these methods here http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Periodic_orbit or http://www.cds.caltech.edu/archive/help/uploads/wiki/files/224/cds140b-perorb.pdf?

Comment: We are only looking at some of the theorems mentioned in the attachment. Anyway, I still can not solve this problem. Any clue that can help me? Please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be observed that the lines $x= 0$ and $y=0$ are invariant sets of the system:
$$
\dot x\big|_{x=0}=0,\quad \dot y\big|_{y=0}=0.
$$
It means that no solution can enter or leave these lines.

In fact, the phase portrait of the system looks as follows:
[image]
(the fixed points are denoted by asterisks).

We know that any closed orbit on a plane must enclose at least one fixed point. But for this system, this is impossible. Any closed orbit here must traverse the "red" solutions, which violates the uniqueness and existence theorem.

Comment: @Moo I used MATLAB (except for the arrows)

Comment: why can you say that must enclose at least one fixed point?

Comment: @Luiza Silva This is a known fact: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle#Finding_limit_cycles

Comment: @Luiza Silva It follows from the index theory